Why is my GET route for searching players by name in Express.js not working?
I am building an API using Node.js and Express.js to manage football players. I want to implement a GET route that allows users to search for a player by their name using a query parameter. However, the route is not working as expected when I test it in Postman.
Here is the code for my search route:
app.get("/joueurs/search", (req, res) => {
    const { nom } = req.query;
    if (!nom) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Please provide a player name to search." });
    }
    const matchingPlayers = joueurs.filter(joueur =>
        joueur.nom.toLowerCase().includes(nom.toLowerCase())
    );
    if (matchingPlayers.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "No players found with this name." });
    }
    res.status(200).json(matchingPlayers);
});

Data:
[
    { "id": 1, "idEquipe": 2, "nom": "Luka Modrić", "numero": 10, "poste": "Milieu" },
    { "id": 2, "idEquipe": 3, "nom": "Luka Jović", "numero": 18, "poste": "Attaquant" },
    { "id": 3, "idEquipe": 1, "nom": "Karim Benzema", "numero": 9, "poste": "Attaquant" }
]

I use Postman but no result and no error
Verified that the joueurs.json file is correctly imported and contains data.
Ensured the server is running and accessible.
Checked the query parameter in Postman (nom with value luka).
Added console.log statements to debug the req.query.nom value, which seems to work as expected.

You should add the request URL you're sending in postman. Also is it possible that it's failing on the ć character? That would possibly be getting escaped in the URL

You say "no result & no error" in Postman, but you are seeing console.log output from your server when Postman makes the request? And while it may not be the response you're looking for, what is the raw response to the request in Postman?
